# Laravel- token is not created on register request

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, jwt

I'm newbie in laravel and I'm working on a project including JWT.
I've changed the user table that was generated by Laravel:
instead of 'name' column , I replaced to 'first_name' and 'last_name' columns.

like that:

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) 
    {

            $table->id();
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
    }
```

I followed the instructions to add the JWT and created AuthController as said.
my Register function looks like that:

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
     $user = User::create([
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'username' => $request->username,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
        ]);

        $token = auth()->login($user);
     
        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
       
    }
```

after checking on Postman, the user was created and added to the table, but without token.
so the request returns empty token.  like that:

```
{

    "access_token": null,
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600

};
```

Why is that?

maybe it's because I've changed the origin columns at the users table?
And what should I do to fix it?

thank you.

Comment: I had a similar issue a while back, can you post the entire AuthController?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you should do the migrations again after you have made some changes to the original columns. But you might have done that already.